# How to resolve the error "SSS_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT" upon connecting to API with certificate on NetSuite?

Tags: ssl-certificate, netsuite, suitescript, connection-timeout, netsuite-rest-api

On NetSuite, I am trying to connect to a third-party API. Their API always expects both the certificate and key part to be provided (an SSL Base64 PEM certificate that also requires a key). I did a connection test on Postman and the test was successful.

However, I am unable to make it work on NetSuite. I get the error:

{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"SSS_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT","message":"The host you are trying to connect to is not responding."...}

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(['N/https/clientCertificate', 'N/log'],
/**
 * @param {clientCertificate} cert
 * @param {log} log
 */
function(cert, log) {

    function connectToXXX() {
        var sandboxUrl = 'https://connect.prelive.xxx.eu/xxxxxxxxx';
        var headers = {
            'Accept'         : '*/*', 
            'Host'           : 'connect.prelive.xxx.eu',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 
            'Connection'     : 'keep-alive',
        };

        try {
            var response = cert.get({
                certId  : 'custcertificaters_xxx_cert_test',
                url     : sandboxUrl, 
                headers : headers
            });
            log.debug('XXX API Response', response.code + ' | ' + response.body);
        } catch(e) {
            log.error('API Connection Failed', e);
        }

    }

    function beforeLoad(context) {
        connectToXXX();       
    }

    return {beforeLoad : beforeLoad}

});
```

For the headers, I tried with the below variations but got the same error.

```
 var headers = {
            'Content-Type'   : 'application/soap+xml'
            'Accept'         : 'application/soap+xml'
        };
```

```
 var headers = {
            'Accept'         : 'application/soap+xml'
        };
```